# Why does a calculation not work when the calculation is placed in the code before the input of the parameters?

Tags: c++

The correct answer for the value of x1=7, x2=3, y1=12, y2=9 is supposed to be 5. This code is giving me 5.9...   I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    double distance;

    distance = sqrt(pow((x2-x1), 2) + pow((y2-y1), 2));

    cout << "Enter x1: ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "Enter x2: ";
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "Enter y1: ";
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "Enter y2: ";
    cin >> y2;

    cout << "The distance between two points is: " << distance << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, due to doing calculations on non-initialized variables (i.e. You do your calculation before reading the values). Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of coding randomly.

Comment: So I should put the formula under the read values?

Comment: @MussieTesfay yes. Otherwise the calculations are done before the input on uninitialized variables. Remember, evaluation is done from the top-down.

Comment: @MussieTesfay What do you think, given the explanation, that I had provided?

Comment: The title of this question needs to be rephrased. "Can't figure out the issue" says absolutely nothing

Comment: @Morgan  Someone has already edited it, but is in the review queue

Comment: It just didn't feel right to do that. I am used to defining all variables before dealing with anything else.

Comment: When writing a program you do not write mathematical equations, but statements that are executed one by one, so you cannot change order any way you want.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: _I am used to defining all variables before dealing with anything else_ What you did was you `declared` the variables. You `define` them when you assign values to them from console input.

Comment: Consider using `x * x` rather than `pow(x, 2)`.  Often it is more accurate and faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation that:

```
distance = sqrt(pow((x2-x1), 2) + pow((y2-y1), 2));
```

will use the values of the variables that the user input is ill-founded. When that line is executed, the variables `x1`, etc are not initialized. Hence, your program has undefined behavior.

Move that line after the line where you read `y2`.

```
// Not good to be here.
// distance = sqrt(pow((x2-x1), 2) + pow((y2-y1), 2));

cout << "Enter x1: ";
cin >> x1;
cout << "Enter x2: ";
cin >> x2;
cout << "Enter y1: ";
cin >> y1;
cout << "Enter y2: ";
cin >> y2;

distance = sqrt(pow((x2-x1), 2) + pow((y2-y1), 2));
```